# Ayuda con history.pushState y keyup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, buscador

necesito orientación sobre esto! Ya que he intentado de varias maneras y no he podido arreglarlo.

El código es

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').on("keyup", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $(this).val(),
        str = window.location.href,
        res = str.split("?"),
        link = res[0] + '?q=' + search + '&' + res[1];
        window.history.pushState(res[0] + '?q=' + search, '', link);
    });
});
```

Explicación:

**str** devuelve = *http://localhost/NewRisus/blog/?sort=new&n=a*

**search** develve = *los caracteres tipiados*

**link** devuelve = *http://localhost/NewRisus/blog/?q=**(los caracteres)**&sort=new&n=a*

pero con **window.history.pushState** me queda *http://localhost/NewRisus/blog/?q=letra&q=letr&q=let&q=le&q=l&sort=new&n=a* y va aumentando mientras voy tipiando, ya que esta dentro de la función de **keyup** lo repetirá por cada letra.

Como hago para evitar eso y que solo vaya agregando los caracteres que se escriban en el input.

Comment: se repite porque por cada interacion estas agregando `q=` +letra
podrias validar que exista antes y en caso tal solo modificarlo para evitar volverlo a agregar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se repite porque por cada interacion estas agregando `'q='+search`
tienes que hacer una validacion de que exista antes y en caso tal solo modificarlo para evitar volverlo a agregar.

## ejemplo:

```
      //si window.location es http://localhost/NewRisus/blog/?sort=new&n=a
      search = "test1";
      path = window.location.pathname; // patname sera igual a /NewRisus/blog/
      query = window.location.search; // seach sera igual a ?sort=new&n=a

      // validamos que soporte el metodo
        if (typeof URLSearchParams !== 'undefined') {
          // inicializamos
          params = new URLSearchParams(query);
          //eliminamos el parametro q
          params.delete('q');
          // pasamos a string
          query=params.toString();
        }
      //creamos la nueva url
      newUrl = `${path}?q=${search}&${query}`;
      
      // redireccionamos
      history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirve mucho...